# Click radio button, change inner icon

Tags: jquery, html

When the user clicks on the label of the radio button. I'd like to change the gear to the selected labels icon. So for example. :

If a user clicks on the tags. The top gear(cog) would change to a tag.

This is my code:

```
var current-icon = $('span.carat i.icon-cog');
$('#hidden-search-filter label').click(function(){
    var icon = $(this).find('i');
    current-icon.val(icon);
});
```

How do I make this possible? [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/100/) to show what Im working with. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this :

```
$('#hidden-search-filter label').on('click', function(){
    $('.carat i:first-child').attr('class', $('i', this).attr('class'));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/103/)

`val()` sets and gets the value of an element, as in:

```
<input type="text" value="It gets this string" />
```

You need to change the class, and using `attr()` (we're trying to change the attribute, not the className property) resets the class to a new value, where addClass and removeClass would add or remove a class while all other classes would be kept etc.

Comment: @adeneo.. +1.. Also would be better to explain to the OP , why his code would not work ?